# C#: Partial Classes

Tags: c#, partial-classes

This is quick confirmation question:

In order to make partial classes work, I initially thought that there would be a main Class `public class ManageDates` and then you would create partial classes like `public partial class ManageDates` to extend the ManageDates class.

But from some experimenting, I've come to find out that if you're going to use partial classes, each individual class must be declared `public partial class [ClassName]` ...

Am I correct in this conclusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, each piece of a partial class must be declared `partial` and reside in the same assembly.

This is because partial classes are just a compiler convenience; once the assembly is created, all of the contents of the class are in a single location.

Comment: +1 for reside in the same assembly and the internals are represented by really just a single class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Each part of the class must be declared using the `partial` keyword.